# Browsing directories in Jupyter dashboard very slow

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm using Jupyter on Windows 7 to browse my local directories, view various files and open jupyter notebooks. However, changing from one to another directory takes around 3 up to 60 seconds, while opening the same folder using File Explorer is close to instantaneous. 
To be specific, the inteface showing the current directory and 'Files', 'Running', 'Clusters' tabs are fast to load. It is the list of files in the current directory that takes a very long time to load.

Is there a way to speed up browsing directories in the Jupyter dashboard? What may be reasons that make the Jupyter dashboard so slow?

Answer (score 1):

Listing directory may be slow for a couple of reasons: 
  - Antivirus checking the behavior of the Jupyter and throttling listing of directories. Try disabling it temporarily to check. 
  - Using old Python. Newer Python (3.6+) have extended `os.listdir()` with `os.scandir()` which newer version of Jupyter notebook make use of. 
  - A lot of hidden files, Jupyter have to list them but won't show them.

We cannot be as fast as Explorer, as explorer can do a lot of optimisations than Jupyter cannot (like explorer can get notified of files changes and thus use efficient caching), while Jupyter can't.

Comment: Thanks. Are you talking about the Ipython kernel that Jupyter is running on? Or do you mean the kernel I run my notebooks on? I have no issues running notebooks, it is only the dashboard that is slow. Can you tell me how to change the (i)python kernell used by the Jupyter dashboard?
- Disabling firewalls did not have any effect
- Checked for hidden files. Not there. Opening folders with only 1 file inside is equally slow.

Comment: The dashboard does not use any kernel, it uses a webserver. Seeing your description I would suggest opening an issue we might need you to try a custom branch or poke at the code to profile why it is so slow.

Answer (score 0):

This was happening to me too.  Not just the directory pages, but the notebook pages were loading slowly too.  In my case, it was caused by an overloaded DNS cache.

From the command prompt (opened as an administrator):

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>ipconfig/flushdns
```